# SQL Server : insert record when values or record do not exist

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012, exists, not-exists

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have two tables: one is called `People` and the other is called `Contacting`

`People` table:

```
ID primary key
NAME
WEBSITE
EMAIL
```

`Contacting` table:

```
ID (foreign key to People ID)
WAY_OF_CONTACTING
REFERENCE
```

The logic goes as follows: for every person there is in the `People`'s table there could be several records on the `Contacting`'s table. Obviously, the relationship between `People` and `Contacting` is one-to-many.

`WAY_OF_CONTACTING` could have only 2 values: "Email" and "Website", and the `REFERENCE` column contains the email or the website's name.

The primary key of the `Contacting` table is a composite primary key consisting of the `ID` and the `Way_Of_Contacting` (this means, for every ID, they can only have up to **one** email and **one** website)

The records on the people's table get deleted every night and get populated throughout the day.

4 things could happen in the People table:

1. Website and Email empty
2. Website empty but not Email
3. Email empty but not Website
4. Neither Website nor Email Empty

My problem is the following:

For every record in the `People` table

- `insert into Contacting` a record when the `ID` **exists** in `Contacting` but **doesn't** have a `record` with `Way_of_Contacting='Website'` or when the ID **doesn't** exist in `Contacting`
- `insert into Contacting` a record when the `ID` **exists** in `Contacting` but **doesn't** have a `record` with `Way_of_Contacting='Website'` or when the ID **doesn't** exist in `Contacting`

In other words:

- If the `People ID` **exists** in the `Contacting` table, check if a record has the value *"Email"* on the field `Way_of_Contacting`.
- If such record doesn't exist, and the `Email` field in the `People table` is not empty, `insert a record`.
- If the `ID` **doesn't** exist and `Email` field in People is not empty, `insert a record`.

Same thing for `Website`

How could this be accomplished?

I've tried using `merge` and `if not exists` but I can't seem to find a correct answer

Comment: *"I've tried using merge and if not exists but I can't seem to find a correct answer"* what were those attempts? Why didnt they work?

Comment: I think you need to clean up the question as seems rather convoluted and not clear why or what you want, I made a start wanting to help but its unclear what the objective is. For a start why are you deleting the People rows when this is a foreign key used by the contacting table.

Comment: In the contacting table why don't you rename ID to people_Id and add a unique primary key. It will save pain later,

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a view instead of a table like below. The advantage being that the view is always updated based on the people table.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Contacting
   AS  
Select
     ID
    ,'Website' as Way_of_Contacting
    ,WEBSITE as Reference   

From People

Where WEBSITE is not null

Union all

Select
     ID
    ,'Email' as Way_of_Contacting
    ,Email as Reference 

From People

Where Email is not null
```